# PUT 2 mysql tables together en show the results together

Tags: php, mysql

how can i put this 2 tables togheter

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM berichten where fromm='$id' AND ontvanger =     '$session->username'  ORDER BY date ASC");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM berichten_send where fromm='$id' AND ontvanger =     '$session->username'  ORDER BY date ASC");
```

this is wat i tried but is not not working

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM berichten LEFT JOIN berichten_send on berichten.id =     berichten_send.id where fromm='$id' AND ontvanger = '$session->username'  ORDER BY date ASC");
$number=mysql_num_rows($result);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo $row['msg'];
echo "<br>";
echo time_stamp($row['date']);
echo "<br>-----------------------<br>";

}
```

Comment: It depends on the resulting data that you want to fetch.

Comment: what' the error message returned?

Comment: no results. also it gives no error

Comment: `UNION`, & you'll have both.

Comment: no where in your code do you check for errors, so its not surprise you see none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial part of your question shows that both tables have  'fromm' and 'ontvanger' fields.

mysql should be complaining about ambiguous fields.

Try

```
.... where berichten.fromm='$id' AND berichten.ontvanger = '$session->username'
```